# How to Change this cases into for-loop

Tags: c#

I have some tables which contain Accounts
I use them inside win what I want is, is there any way to change this cases to auto mode? Because there are many numbers and it takes a long time to write.
Some example
ledger ID is 100, so Subsidiary Ledger Will be 10001 
Ledger ID is 101, so Subsidiary Ledger Will be 10101 
Ledger ID is 205, so Subsidiary Ledger Will be 20501
Here is my code

```html
public static decimal accountDefinitiveID { get; set; }
 
public static void GetDefinitiveID(decimal LedgerID)
{
    var query = database.Database.SqlQuery<tbl_AccountDefinitive>("Select Top(1) *From tbl_AccountDefinitive Where LedgerID='" + LedgerID + "' Order By DefinitiveID DESC");
    var result = query.ToList();
    if (result.Count == 1)
    {
        accountDefinitiveID = result[0].DefinitiveID + 1;
    }
    if (result.Count == 0)
    {
        switch (Convert.ToInt32(LedgerID))
        {
            case 100:
                accountDefinitiveID = 10001;
                break;
            case 101:
                accountDefinitiveID = 10101;
                break;
            case 102:
                accountDefinitiveID = 10201;
                break;
            case 200:
                accountDefinitiveID = 20001;
                break;
            case 201:
                accountDefinitiveID = 20101;
                break;
            case 305:
                accountDefinitiveID = 30501;
                break;
            case 400:
                accountDefinitiveID = 40001;
                break;
            case 509:
                accountDefinitiveID = 50901;
                break;
            case 600:
                accountDefinitiveID = 60001;
                break;
            case 700:
                accountDefinitiveID = 70001;
                break;
            case 800:
                accountDefinitiveID = 80001;
                break;
            case 900:
                accountDefinitiveID = 90001;
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you just want to append `01` to the end of the value:

```
public static decimal accountDefinitiveID { get; set; }

public static void GetDefinitiveID(decimal LedgerID)
{
    var query = database.Database.SqlQuery<tbl_AccountDefinitive>("Select Top(1) *From tbl_AccountDefinitive Where LedgerID='" + LedgerID + "' Order By DefinitiveID DESC");
    var result = query.ToList();

    if (result.Count == 1)
    {
        accountDefinitiveID = result[0].DefinitiveID + 1;
    }
    else
    {
        accountDefinitiveID = Convert.ToInt32(LedgerID) * 100 + 1;
    }
}
```